# Retornar array() em jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho a seguinte lista HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th width="50" class="text-center">#</th>
            <th>Item do Pacote</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            <th>Vencimento</th>
            <th width="50" class="text-center"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50" class="text-center">1</td>
            <td>Salgados - 100 Un</td>
            <td>R$ 150,00</td>
            <td width="200px">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="itens[0][data_vencimento]" id="itens[data_vencimento][]">            
            </td>
            <td width="50" class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="itens[0][item]" id="itens[item]" class="checados" value="150,00|1"></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td width="50" class="text-center">2</td>
            <td>Doces - 100 Un</td>
            <td>R$ 114,00</td>
            <td width="200px">
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="itens[1][data_vencimento]" id="itens[data_vencimento][]">            
            </td>
            <td width="50" class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="itens[1][item]" id="itens[item]" class="checados" value="114,00|2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50" class="text-center">3</td>
            <td>Refrigerante - 10 un</td>
            <td>R$ 85,00</td>
            <td width="200px">
            <input type="date" class="form-control array_teste" name="itens[2][data_vencimento]" id="itens[data_vencimento][]">            
            </td>
            <td width="50" class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" name="itens[2][item]" id="itens[item]" class="array_teste" value="85,00|3"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Preciso recuperar todos estes dados que estão dentro dos campos, através de um jQuery.
Eu tentei fazer desta maneira:

```
$("#salvar_festa").click(function() {

    var itens = $(".array_teste").serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        url: basePath + 'evento/salvar_festa',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            itens: itens
        },
    })
    .done(function(ret) {
        console.log("success");
        $('#mensagePage').html(ret);
    }); 

});
```

Mas desta forma, não consigo o retorno dos objetos da array, que devem retornar da seguinte maneira:

```
[item] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [data_vencimento] => 2016-12-05
                [itens] => 150,00|1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [data_vencimento] => 2016-12-07
                [itens] => 114,00|2
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [data_vencimento] => 2016-12-22
                [itens] => 85,00|3
            )               
    )
```

Mas não tenho a mínima ideia de como resolver esta questão.
Dentro do salvar_festa no PHP, eu tenho então o print_r($_POST);

Meu retorno via print_r($_POST):

```
Array
(
    [itens] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => itens[0][data_vencimento]
                    [value] => 2016-12-01
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => itens[0][item]
                    [value] => 150,00|1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => itens[1][data_vencimento]
                    [value] => 2016-12-01
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => itens[1][item]
                    [value] => 114,00|2
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [name] => itens[2][data_vencimento]
                    [value] => 2016-12-01
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [name] => itens[2][item]
                    [value] => 85,00|3
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor _"o retorno dessa array, vem desajustado"_? talvez com um exemplo do que tens e de como querias que ficasse?

Comment: Posso sim Sérgio, vou reformular para que possas entender melhor.

Comment: Editei, acho que fica melhor pra você compreender.

Comment: O HTML pode ser mudado? se estás a usar jQuery para gerar a array a enviar por ajax não precisas da lógica de nomes como `name="itens[0][data_vencimento]"`

Comment: Sim, porque o HTML é gerado por um loop no PHP.

Comment: Perfeito, porém, de igual forma, o meu retorno continua sendo name,value, porém, preciso quer retorne item e data_vencimento... como a array que postei

Comment: É isto que queres? -> https://jsfiddle.net/vsroLu9m/1/

Comment: Não seria, ele repete as arrays()

Comment: Tens razão, tinha um bug: https://jsfiddle.net/vsroLu9m/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes mudar o HTML para ter o `name` simples, como as chaves dos objetos que queres na array. E depois podes ir buscar o conteúdo para gerar o array assim:

```
var array = $('tr:has(input)').filter(function() {
    return $('[type="checkbox"]:checked', this).length;
}).map(function() {
    return $('input', this).get().reduce(function(obj, input) {
        obj[input.name] = input.value;
        return obj;
    }, {});
}).get();
```

Um exemplo seria assim ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vsroLu9m/3/)):

```js
var array = $('tr:has(input)').filter(function() {
    return $('[type="checkbox"]:checked', this).length;
}).map(function() {
    return $('input', this).get().reduce(function(obj, input) {
        obj[input.name] = input.value;
        return obj;
    }, {});
}).get();

console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th width="50" class="text-center">#</th>
            <th>Item do Pacote</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            <th>Vencimento</th>
            <th width="50" class="text-center"></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50" class="text-center">1</td>
            <td>Salgados - 100 Un</td>
            <td>R$ 150,00</td>
            <td width="200px">
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="data_vencimento" id="itens[data_vencimento][]">
            </td>
            <td width="50" class="text-center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="item" id="itens[item]" class="checados" value="150,00|1">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50" class="text-center">2</td>
            <td>Doces - 100 Un</td>
            <td>R$ 114,00</td>
            <td width="200px">
                <input type="date" class="form-control" name="data_vencimento" id="itens[data_vencimento][]">
            </td>
            <td width="50" class="text-center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="item" id="itens[item]" class="checados" value="114,00|2">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="50" class="text-center">3</td>
            <td>Refrigerante - 10 un</td>
            <td>R$ 85,00</td>
            <td width="200px">
                <input type="date" class="form-control array_teste" name="data_vencimento" id="itens[data_vencimento][]">
            </td>
            <td width="50" class="text-center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="item" id="itens[item]" class="array_teste" value="85,00|3">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sim, há apenas um porém, ele só pode me retornar os que foram checados e preenchidos, porque é uma opção de escolha do usuário, ele seleciona o que ele vai querer na festa dele. Neste caso.

Comment: @AndréBaill ah, estou a ver... então seria assim: https://jsfiddle.net/vsroLu9m/3/

Comment: Perfeito desta maneira @Sergio, a única coisa que eu removi, foi para não retornar em Json, porque vou tratar o retorno via PHP, para inclusão na base de dados, mas demais, é isso mesmo. Muito obrigado! Funcionou!

Comment: Se puder, só edita colocando a sua resposta que postou no jsfiddle, ;)

Comment: @AndréBaill feito!